# C# DrawElipse Method without specifying a fill

Tags: c#, graphics, kinect, drawingcontext

Simple Question - How do I use drawing context to make an Ellipse but not fill it with colour?

At the moment I have:

```
 drawingContext.DrawEllipse(drawBrush, null, jointPoints[jointType],   JointThickness, JointThickness);
```

This gives me an Ellipse that is filled with colour at every joint position tracked with the Kinect.

I want to display an outter circle without a fill, how can I do this? 
[image]

For Example like the image above, how would I make the outter circle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply pass `null` for the brush and pass in a `Pen` of the desired color instead.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms606797(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The brush with which to fill the ellipse. This is optional, and can be null. If the brush is null, no fill is drawn.

Comment: Oh wow thank you so much, I couldn't find see that when I checked sorry